# Difficulty Running Multiple Versions of R from Command Line

Tags: r, macos, installation

I'm in a team that is running multiple cronjobs that call R scripts from a remote machine (macos). My colleague needs to run 3.6 for a new script, while a package that is essential to mine has not been updated for it yet. I'm trying to put multiple installations on the same computer so we just specify which "R" version to call in the cronjob.

I know installing from source isn't recommended on macos, so I've been trying to follow the directions here https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Multiple-versions and ran the pkgutil --forget commands to prevent the R 3.6 installation from overwriting the R.framework/Versions/3.5 directory.

Here are the pkgutil commands that I ran:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.x86_64.tcltk.x11
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.el-capitan.GUI.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.R.el-capitan.fw.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget org.r-project.x86_64.texinfo
```

Yet after installing 3.6 from CRAN, when I run the following line:

```
Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/bin/R
```

Instead of the 3.5.3 console running in the terminal, the 3.6 console pops up.

I'm confused with what to do here - I've also used

```
ls -la 3.5/Resources/bin | grep "/->"
```

to check and see if a symlink was created during the install that would change the version/location but get no results, and when I run Rscript --version in the same directory as the R path shown above, I get the following output:

```
R scripting front-end version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
```

Though when I try to run my script using this location of Rscript I get the same error that I did when running it using R 3.6. However, once I reinstalled R 3.5.3 the script ran fine.

Basically, I think somehow the most recently installed version of R seems to override and run no matter what I do to try and insure that an older version runs instead. Can someone help me piece together how or why this is happening, or provide a suggestion as to how to install R 3.6 as the default "R" while still allowing me to run 3.5.3 for certain scripts as needed?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. What you observed is clearly mentioned on https://cran.rstudio.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-macOS: "However, R.APP will always run the ‘current’ version, that is the last installed version.". So far, I don't know how to solve the problem either. Using Rswitch worked very well to switch R versions manually, but i don't know how to integrate Rswitch to command lines.